Can some node 1 gain more Bonacich centrality by linking with node 2 rather than 3, node 2 with 3 rather than 1, and node 3 with 1 rather than 2?
Consider any unweighted and undirected graph, or adjacency matrix, G, composed of N rows and N columns. The entry $g_{ij}$ of row $i$ and column $j$ of G equals 1 if nodes i and j are linked, and 0 otherwise. The Bonacich centralities of nodes are given in vector
$$B=[I_{N}- \lambda G]^{-1}1$$
where row $i$ denotes the Bonacich centrality of node $i$, where $I_{N}$ is the identity matrix of dimension $N$, $\lambda$ is a parameter such that $0<\lambda<\frac{1}{N-1}$, and $1$ is vector of one's, composed of $N$ rows.
Suppose that some nodes 1, 2 and 3 are not linked between each other, i.e., $g_{12}=g_{13}=g_{23}=0$. Is it possible that node 1 gains more Bonacich centrality by linking with node 2 than with node 3, that node 2 gains more Bonacich centrality by linking with node 3 than with node 1, and that node 3 gains more Bonacich centrality by linking with node 1 than with node 2?
It is worth noting that the Bonacich centrality that any agent $i$ gains by linking with some agent $j$ equals:
$$(\frac{1-\lambda m_{ij}}{(1-\lambda m_{ij})^2-\lambda^2m_{jj}m_{ii}}-1)b_i+(\frac{1}{(1-\lambda m_{ij})^2-\lambda^2m_{jj}m_{ii}})\lambda m_{ii}b_j$$
where $m_{ij}$ corresponds to the entry of row $i$ and column $j$ of matrix $M=[I_{N}- \lambda G]^{-1}$, and $b_i$ and $b_j$ correspond to the Bonacich centralities of nodes i and j respectively. It is also worth noting that for any pair $i,j$, we have $m_{ij}=m_{ji}$.
Even if you do not know or find the answer to the question above, any hint on how I could arrive to the answer is appreciated. Thanks a lot!
